# Calibration of the Atmel M90E32AS Energy Metering IC

Tags: energy, atmel, calibration, metering

I'm working on an energy metering project featuring the Atmel M90E32AS, connected with an ESP32-S3.

From the [Application Notes](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/Atmel-46103-SE-M90E32AS-ApplicationNote.pdf) of the IC, I understand that it needs to be calibrated first. However, I'm unable to understand how to calibrate the voltage, current, and power offset registers.

Following is a screenshot from the Application Notes for the calibration process of the offset registers.

[image: Screenshot from Application Notes]

For calibration of Phase 1 voltage, it says **Ub=Uc=Un, Ua=0, Ia=0**. I understand Ua=0 and Ia=0 mean I trip the breaker on Phase 1, so the voltage and current are 0.

But what does it mean by **Ub=Uc=Un**? Should I trip the breakers on Phase 2 and Phase 3 too and short both with N? Or should I keep the breakers on and continue with the calibration process?

Thanks in advance!